# .htaccess and redirecting nonexistent files and directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to figure out how to program a .htaccess file to redirect any file or directory that does not exist to the index.html file in the web root.

I sort of figured it out with this directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

The problem is that an HTTP 404 error is still returned by the web server. I'd like to show a permanent redirect for all these files instead. It is important that a 404 error NOT be returned.

Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this rule to your htaccess file instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,R=301]
```

This checks that the request isn't a file, isn't a directory, and isn't a symlink. Then redirects whatever the request is to `/index.html`.

Comment: This definitely redirects errantly requested directories and files. Thanks! I need to inspect the web log but I can't imagine Apache would pass back a HTTP 404 error.

Comment: Okay with some testing this apparently has a problem. The full URL does not show when the page is legitimate. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Mark What do you mean by "the full URL does not show"? Show where? In the location bar? The page doesn't get rendered?

Comment: Exactly. The page redirects properly but the URL field is blank. Could it have something to do with links?

Comment: @Mark No idea why you'd get redirected to a blank URL. The rule above clearly makes it go to `/index.html`, which isn't blank. Don't know what you mean by it having to do with links, I don't know how you have your site set up.

Comment: Well, I made it / instead of /index.html because the site has some Miva shopping cart software and index.html is not the default page, although the page exists. The problem seems to be that the rule is being applied to all pages, not just those with incorrect file names or absent directories.

Comment: @Mark The `!-f/d/l` checks only physical files and directories. If you've got some sort of CMS that routes URI's to content, and they don't physically exist on the harddrive as files and directories, then none of those checks will work.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll let the customer know.

Comment: It may be that symbolic links should not be used because Miva creates a virtual link?

Comment: @Mark a symbolic link is a physical file on the harddrive, that has a size of "0" and points to another physical file. It has nothing to do with the magical routing that CMS's and the like use

Comment: The solution is correct but not in my case. This is because Miva shopping cart software is creating virtual pages on the fly that masquerade as real URLs. So of course these pages are not going to be found and trigger the rule. Curiously the virtual page is served but the URL does not appear in the browser. Anyhow, I appreciate the solution even if I can't quite apply it my situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a convinient [`FallbackResource` directive in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource)

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

Comment: The `FallbackResource` will serve the `/index.html` page but not permanently redirect. It only silently serves the resource.

Comment: I’m not sure the OP was thinking about a HTTP Redirect